# How does one import filtered data from “Sheet2” into “Sheet1?

Tags: google-sheets, filtered-lookup

Objective: import filtered data from “Sheet2” into “Sheet1.”

Data is filtered in “Sheet2”, an expense table with dollar amounts in column A, and categories such as “fuel”, “meals”, “parking”, etc. in column B.

I understand that one way to do it is to make a separate sheet for each category and SUM those amounts, and import them into “Sheet1”. I am able to do that, however,  I would like to use one sheet and some method to do the following:

In “Sheet2” filter the data for a determined category and display a SUM for that category in a predetermined cell in “Sheet1”.

[I have shared the sheets here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MnIPXFC9yPA6RUpUY7r7LdtszoG0U_Lr26UsklVN8PE/edit?usp=sharing)

If I am shown how to do this for one category I will be able to copy and paste the function into the appropriate cells in “Sheet1” for the remaining categories.

I am aware that I may not be asking this in the best way. Thanks for all your help.

~ Joe D

Comment: @BrunoCésar Link doesn't work. Also I thought google spreadsheets questions we're allowed on SO? Not sure about the filtered lookup tag on this though

Comment: Sorry, this link: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=sumif(Sheet2!B:B,"fuel",Sheet2!A:A)
```

The above formula works for fuel, simply change `"fuel"` to whatever you are trying to  sum.

If you wanted to change what was in Sheet1, cell A1 to `fuel` instead of `fuel total` and changed all the other values in column A to match. Removing `total` (remembering to remove the space too)

You could then use this formula in cell B1, drag it down, and as new expenses were added. It would look at the name of the expense and sum it.

```
=sumif(Sheet2!B:B,A1,Sheet2!A:A)
```

If you didn't want to take out the `total` then the following formula should work if placed in B1 and dragged down.

```
=sumif(Sheet2!B:B,SUBSTITUTE(A1," total",""),Sheet2!A:A)
```

Comment: Munkey this is perfect! So simple. 

Inside the parens what is this asking for?

Comment: @JoeD Not sure what you mean exactly, But SUMIF takes 2 or 3 arguments.
SUMIF(1st what cells/range has the data we are going to test, 2nd what does that cell in the 1st bit have to compare to. This case, equal to,   3rd (optional) where is the stuff we have to add up if it's not the 1st argument)

2nd argument can be a cell reference. A1. A value, like "fuel" or a number 3, or a formula. Like the substitute one above that removes the space and word total from A1, resulting in just fuel.
Below is some info on SumIf function
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en-GB&rd=1